# Coding Wordpress/PHP Problem

Tags: php, wordpress, date

Im having a bit of a problem with wordpress. On my site there is a bit that displays voucher now what i want is when that voucher expires i want the voucher details div not too show.

Here is the code from single.php

```
<?php if(have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();


        $image = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'image',true);
        $writer = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'writer',true);
        $code = get_post_meta($post->ID,'vcode',true);
        $store = get_post_meta($post->ID,'store',true);
        $expiry = strtotime(get_post_meta($post->ID,'expiry',true));
        $desc = get_post_meta($post->ID,'description',true);
        $datetoday = strtotime(date('Y/m/d'));
        ?>
```

this brings all the data from custom fields

heres the voucher div

```
<?php if($expiry > $datetoday){?>
        <div class="voucherDetails">
            <h2>Voucher Details</h2>
            <div class="left">
                <ul>
                    <li>Code: <?php echo $code;?></li>
                    <li>Expires: <?php echo $expiry;?></li>
                    <li><a class="more-link" href="<?php echo $store;?>" title="Visit Store">Visit Store!</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="desc right">
                <h4>Description</h4>
                <p><?php echo $desc;?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php }?>
```

Now when i run this with the expiry with any value the voucher doesn't show The value in store is DD/MM/YYYY

Can't work it out, all help appreciated,

Thanks
Joe

Comment: What are the values of `$expiry` and `$datetoday` before your if statement?

Comment: added what the values are in main question :)

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
  $datetoday = strtotime(date('d/m/Y'));
```

to be

```
  $datetoday = strtotime(date('Y/m/d'));
```

Try run the following as an example of how it differs:

```
$datetoday = strtotime(date('d/m/Y'));
var_dump($datetoday);
var_dump(date("F j, Y, g:i a", $datetoday));


$datetoday = strtotime(date('Y/m/d'));
var_dump($datetoday);
var_dump(date("F j, Y, g:i a", $datetoday));
```

Edit: Alternatively use strtotime("now") if you want the precise timestamp to the very minute

Comment: To be fair though, the absolute safest is to use a ISO 8601 format.

See the below taken from php.net:
Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed.

To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD) dates or DateTime::createFromFormat() when possible.

Comment: Tried still no luck, if i change formatting will that not effect whole site? See edits  for the code i have now :) thanks :)

Comment: Could you post the actual values stored in those variables?

So to humour my curiosity, could you post the output from the following:

`<?php 
var_dump('TodayTimeStamp:' , $datetoday);
var_dump('TodayConv:' , date("F j, Y, g:i a", $datetoday));

var_dump('Expiry: ' , get_post_meta($post->ID,'expiry',true));
var_dump('ExpiryTimestamp: ', $expiry);
var_dump('ExpiryConv: ', date("F j, Y, g:i a", $datetoday));
?>`

Comment: This is the output from the code you posted :string(15) "TodayTimeStamp:" int(1310342400) string(10) "TodayConv:" string(23) "July 11, 2011, 12:00 am" string(8) "Expiry: " string(0) "" string(17) "ExpiryTimestamp: " bool(false) string(12) "ExpiryConv: " string(23) "July 11, 2011, 12:00 am"

Comment: the expiry should be outputting the 7/08/2011 in this instance :S thats the date i entered into custom field.